# Extension method on custom collection throwing error

Tags: c#, linq, extension-methods, ienumerator

I'm creating a custom collection like this.

```
 public class ClientBusinessEntityCollection<T> : ICollection<T> where T : EntityBase
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The list business objects
    /// </summary>
    private List<T> listBusinessObjects = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="KddiBusinessEntityCollection{T}"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    public ClientBusinessEntityCollection()
    {
        this.listBusinessObjects = new List<T>();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="KddiBusinessEntityCollection{T}"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="collection">The collection.</param>
    public ClientBusinessEntityCollection(IEnumerable<T> collection)
    {
        this.listBusinessObjects = new List<T>(collection);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the number of elements contained in the <see cref="T:System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1" />.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The count.</value>
    /// <returns>The number of elements contained in the <see cref="T:System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1" />.</returns>
    public int Count
    {
        get { return this.listBusinessObjects.Count; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the <see cref="`0"/> at the specified index.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="index">The index.</param>
    /// <returns>`0.</returns>
    public T this[long index]
    {
        get
        {
            return this.listBusinessObjects[(int)index];
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets a value indicating whether the <see cref="T:System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1" /> is read-only.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value><c>true</c> if this instance is read only; otherwise, <c>false</c>.</value>
    /// <returns>true if the <see cref="T:System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1" /> is read-only; otherwise, false.</returns>
    public bool IsReadOnly
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Adds an item to the <see cref="T:System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1" />.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="item">The object to add to the <see cref="T:System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1" />.</param>
    public void Add(T item)
    {
        this.listBusinessObjects.Add(item);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Removes all items from the <see cref="T:System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1" />.
    /// </summary>
    public void Clear()
    {
        this.listBusinessObjects.Clear();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Determines whether the <see cref="T:System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1" /> contains a specific value.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="item">The object to locate in the <see cref="T:System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1" />.</param>
    /// <returns>true if <paramref name="item" /> is found in the <see cref="T:System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1" />; otherwise, false.</returns>
    public bool Contains(T item)
    {
        return this.listBusinessObjects.Contains(item);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sorts the collection.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sorter">The sorter.</param>
    public void SortCollection(Func<EntityBase, object> sorter)
    {
        //// TODO : IMPLEMENT SORTING HERE.
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Copies to.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="array">The array.</param>
    /// <param name="arrayIndex">Index of the array.</param>
    public void CopyTo(T[] array, int arrayIndex)
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Removes the first occurrence of a specific object from the <see cref="T:System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1" />.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="item">The object to remove from the <see cref="T:System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1" />.</param>
    /// <returns>true if <paramref name="item" /> was successfully removed from the <see cref="T:System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1" />; otherwise, false. This method also returns false if <paramref name="item" /> is not found in the original <see cref="T:System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1" />.</returns>
    public bool Remove(T item)
    {
        return this.listBusinessObjects.Remove(item);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns an enumerator that iterates through the collection.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>A <see cref="T:System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator`1" /> that can be used to iterate through the collection.</returns>
    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.listBusinessObjects.GetEnumerator();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns an enumerator that iterates through a collection.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>An <see cref="T:System.Collections.IEnumerator" /> object that can be used to iterate through the collection.</returns>
    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.listBusinessObjects.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

now I have a collection like this

```
public ClientBusinessEntityCollection<MyClass> Collection {get; set;}
```

Now the problem is that when I write LINQ statement on "Collection" it throws null reference exception.

```
Collection.OrderBy(item=>item.Order);
```

The collection has an underlying List , but unlike List when you hover your mouse over my custom "Collection" it doesn't shown the number of items. How should I make extension method pick values from the underlying List object when writing LINQ over my custom collection?

Do I need to write custom IEnumerator?

Comment: A `NullReferenceException` when iterating over a list with LINQ generally means one of the items in the list is `null`... have you checked that isn't the case?

Comment: what fails is this statement
                this.ApplicationBrowser.Navigate(this.ExtensionObject.EndPoints.OrderBy(endpoint => endpoint.Order).First().Url.AbsoluteUri);

Comment: it fails on OrderBy, but if I use "First()" it works

Comment: Then one of them is `null`.. as I stated. `OrderBy` must touch all elements in the list. `First` just touches the first.. so one of the items that _isn't_ the first item is `null`.

Comment: well, "Order" is an integer and all 5 "EndPoint" record has a value for "Order".

Comment: any idea people? otherwise, there is no point for me to create a custom collection.

Comment: Can you try (as a test) making the underlying list public, then calling OrderBy on that? If that fails too, we can be sure the error is in your data. If it succeeds, we can be sure the error is in your `ICollection<T>` implementation.

Comment: I tried the same, none of the objects are null, I think the problem is with Enumerator somewhere. see the image in this link, [error](http://sdrv.ms/19lAZFo)    
This happened when I did a "ToList()" on EndPoint collection.

Comment: Are there any other recommended ways of creating a custom collection?

Comment: Unfortunately I've to add an `Items` property in the definition and I'm not feeling good about it. Hope someone has some other idea.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass through any enumerator-related calls made to your collection to your underlying list, as follows:

```
public class MyTest<T> : ICollection<T>
{
    private List<T> myUnderlyingList = new List<T>();

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return myUnderlyingList.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }

.... etc.
```

Then LINQ will simply be 'seeing' the underlying List when it performs its operations.

The other thing to make sure is that your underlying `List<T>` is populated correctly with valid data before you run any LINQ methods on it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but as I said, I have already implemented all methods on ICollection<T> and this is one of them.

Comment: Ok! In that case, can you post your implementation? If there's a problem with the implementation, that could be the source of your error..

Comment: Edit your original question and post it there.

Comment: in the answer textbox, press ctrl-k and then paste your code.

Comment: @Baldrick can you elaborate more please?

Comment: Can you try in the debugger to look at your underlying list BEFORE you call 'OrderBy'. Make sure every entry is valid by clicking and expanding each one (you said there are only 5).